# Changing nth column from the end of the line, on multiple lines

Tags: vim

I want to change in vim the following text:

```
test aatest
aaaa test a2test
xxxxx test 4 xctesc
```

to

```
test a5test
aaaa test a5test
xxxxx test 4 x5tesc
```

I want to change the 5th to last character of each line into `5`

Is there a command that can change the nth column relative to the last column on multiple lines?

Comment: nth row? What does relative mean? Do you mean nth column?

Comment: The shortest command which solves your example test case is `:%s/\d/4/`. Do you have a more unique test case that doesn't work with this command?

Comment: i made the case more complex. Does that help with my question?

Comment: `:%norm $4hr5`? Still not sure what this has to do with "relative to last row", though.

Comment: I cannot understand the requirement ...

Comment: think i got row and column mixed. @kent i just wanted to change the nth column of each line. mateen gave the answer to my problem. i needed to change my example otherwise people get to specific with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution A

Already mentioned in the comments: For each line, go to the end, move 4 left, replace.

```
:%normal! $4hr5
```

#### Solution B

With `:substitute`: match the 5 last characters, capturing the first and last four separately, then modify in the replacement.

```
:%substitute/\(.\)\(....\)$/5\2/
```